# Torque require to rotate a shaft

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, torque

[image]

I have a solid cylinder (shaft) that I want to rotate around its axis. The cylinder is supported by two bearings at its ends. No other loads than the weight are applied to the cylinder.
My question is; how much torque it needed to rotate the shaft?
I don't know how to applied the friction coef. of the GT2 and bearing.
2. how to calculate the torque required to maintain the cylinder rotating at the desired speed once it reaches it. From what I understood, it is dependent on the friction at the bearings only.

Comment: Where are your equations (e.g., equation 2)? What load is the shaft intended to turn?

Comment: There's no equation; it was a mistake when I was editing. The load is only the mass of the shaft itself. I don't know the exact mass of the cylinder, just want to check the equations need it to solve this problem.